# error: undefined reference to cv::imwrite, что за проблема здесь?

Tags: cmake, cmakelists

Я работаю с native `Android` и использую `CMake`. Мне нужно использовать метод `cv :: imwrite` из `OpenCV`, но когда я использую его в своем коде, я получаю такую ошибку:

```
error: undefined reference to cv::imwrite
```

естественно #include тоже добавлены

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Вроде все правильно добавил в `CMakeList.txt`

```
...
set(pathToOpenCv $ENV{OPEN_CV_PATH})
include_directories(${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

target_link_libraries(decoder_engine_lib
        mediandk
        oboe::oboe
        android
        lib_opencv
        ${log-lib}
)
...
```

Что я упускаю здесь? Почему я получаю эту ошибку?

Comment: андроид не любит в подчерки в именах библиотек попробуй переименовать. еще проверь платформу под которую собираешь. может у тебя там не все  цели перечислены. либо компилятор не находит ближайшую перегрузку по типу параметров.

Comment: во-первых, функция imwrite находится в `imgcodecs` модуле. Ему соответствет одноименный заголовок и библиотека. Сдесь явно проблема с линковкой и что-то не видно, чтобы вы линковали эту библиотеку. Вообще почему вы именно так подключаете opencv, а не через `find_package`? На то есть какие-то объективные причины?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я не помню точно в чем было дело, но вроде это было как то связано в андроидом, ему нужны были .so файлы или что то такое. Вроде `find_package` в случае с openCV не работает для андроид или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko "ему нужны были .so файлы или что-то такое" - прошу прощения за вопрос, но вы точно знаете с++?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko по поводу find_package и android - не писал под андроид, но не вижу ни одной причины, почему find_package не должен работать на android

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch "вы точно знаете с++" сложно ответить точно, смотря как оценивать знания:) скажем что последние пол года переодически с ним работаю)) Прошу прощения - но почему вы задали этот вопрос?:)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko потому что `.so` - это обозначение для разделяемых библиотек в UNIX системах. А вы в комменте написал так, буд-то не знаете, что это за файлы такие...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не совсем понял с какой целью ты интересовался моим знанием с++, какая разница, что такое вообще so вопрос не в этом. Я сказал про so так как (написано в вопросе) я работаю с андроид, ядро у него unix то есть он не работает с dll как винд, а работает с so. для того, чтоб работать с so нужны хедер файлы для описания и собственно сам so для линковки. так что я не пойму в чем был твой вопрос

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko почему? Потому что я вообще-то ответил уже на ваш вопрос... Да и вопрос уровня новичка: тут банальная проблема линковки (о чем, повторюсь, я уже писал)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch :) "Потому что я ответил на ваш вопрос", обьективная причина:) и во вторых пока, что я не вижу никаких ответов на вопрос, вижу коментарии и догадки. То, что здесь проблема линковки это понятно (не нужно тут быть слишком умным чтоб заметить), не понятно, что именно ему не хватает и как исправить, так как мне кажется я подключил все что нужно. Если есть желание выразить ответ - это приветствуется, пожалуйста, там есть кнопка дать ответ. Я отмечу как правильный нет проблем

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko вы очень не внимательны! Перечитайте мой первый коммент, там написано: во-первых, функция imwrite находится в imgcodecs модуле. Ему соответствет одноименный заголовок и библиотека. Тобишь у вас банально не слинкована библиотека `libimgcodecs.so`. Название может отличаться! поэтому-то и следует использовать `find_package` (и не только поэтому)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko надеюсь теперь вы поняли почему я задал вопрос про знание с++? Это проблема уровня новичка и не ожидаешь такого вопроса от участника с репутацией больше собственной